# merge two column with date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need merge two column to date format

input

```
month    year 
----     ----
7         2013
```

The result should be come date format like this  (DD/MM/YYYY) :

```
New_Date
--------
01/07/2013
```

Comment: OP, At least you can review all the answers properly, this is not limited to you anyone will go through this question and be searching for best answer. I don't think that is the best answer that you have chosen.

Comment: thanks Mr @Suraz
I thank all those who answered ..
I'm not a professor to evaluate the answers
only >>> I choose with what suits me I do not underestimate anyone ... sorry for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example this:

```
select convert(date, '01/' + convert(varchar(2), month) + '/' + convert(varchar(4), year), 101)
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of your data is depended on the collation, not how you store it.
To get the date, try this:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check This: Suppose you have variable declaration as below and you can get the desired output in desired form by using `CONVERT`

```
DECLARE @year INT = '2017', @month INT = '7'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, 1), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
```

OUTPUT:

```
DD/MM/YYYY
01/07/2017
```

You have so many date format which you can use to get output in various format please check this http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
SELECT RIGHT('00'+CAST('1' AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + '/' + RIGHT('00'+CAST('7' AS   
VARCHAR(2)),2) + '/' + CAST('2013' AS VARCHAR(4))
```